Pcolor with unequal intervals?
I am trying to use gridlines with over a heat map. I have used pcolor() and my imported dataset from excel. The lines are not equal for some reason.
My excel data set is supposed to indicate frequency of injuries at each 1x1mm box. I want 1x1mm boxes on my heat map. The pcolor lines are not lining up with each other.
Is there a way to make the gridlines even and representative of 1x1 boxes (reflective of my data array)?
heatmap using pcolor() with not equal lines
% Initialize MATLAB
close all;
clc;
clear all;
%read excel data
patella = xlsread('newheatmap', 'patella1%');
lfc = xlsread('newheatmap', 'lfc1%edge');

rng('default');
fig = figure();
tcl = tiledlayout(fig, 2, 1);
n = 2;  % number of heatmaps (assuming you have four matrices)
h = gobjects(n, 1); 

data1 = patella;
data2 = lfc;

cmin = min([data1(:); data2(:)]);  % Determine global minimum value
cmax = max([data1(:); data2(:)]);  % Determine global maximum value

for i = 1:n
    ax = nexttile(tcl); 
    if i == 1
   
        h(i) = pcolor(data1);
        

    elseif i == 2
     
        h(i) = pcolor(data2);
        % Add a horizontal line at y = 39.4 to the heatmap corresponding to data2
        hold on; % Enable hold to plot additional elements on the heatmap
        line([min(get(ax, 'XLim')), max(get(ax, 'XLim'))], [39.4, 39.4], 'Color', 'white', 'LineWidth', 1);
        line([min(get(ax, 'XLim')), max(get(ax, 'XLim'))], [49.4, 49.4], 'Color', 'white', 'LineWidth', 1);
        line([min(get(ax, 'XLim')), max(get(ax, 'XLim'))], [29.4, 29.4], 'Color', 'white', 'LineWidth', 1);
        hold off; % Release hold
       
    end
    %shading(ax, 'flat');  % Ensure flat shading
    colormap(ax, 'jet');  % Set colormap (you can change 'jet' to any other colormap)
    caxis([cmin, cmax]);  % Set common color limits for all heatmaps
    axis equal tight;
   

end

% Create global colorbar
cb = colorbar(ax);
cb.Layout.Tile = 'East';
cb.Ticks = linspace(cmin, cmax, 10);  % You can adjust the number of ticks as needed

I tried mesh() and defining the axes, but this did not change anything.
I tried grid on; and then defined x and y ticks by 1 up to length of the data array. This did not work for me as the gridlines did not correlate with my heat boxes. The lines should exactly alight with the colors in the map.

"The pcolor lines are not lining up with each other" what do you mean by that? Can you maybe explain in a little more details what is wrong in the current output, and what you would want it to look like?
